# Why does `values` perform faster when concatenating columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to create a new column from the concatenation of subset of columns on the same row. Since large data sets is involved, I tried several ways to do so. I noticed that using `values` in `join` is about 2-3x faster that without it (see below). Any idea on why and when this is true?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': {0: 'United States',
  1: 'Syria', 
  2: 'Russia',
  3: 'China',
  4: 'Philippines',
  5: 'Russia',
  6: 'North Korea',
  7: 'Philippines',
  8: 'Finland',
  9: 'Kenya'},
 'car': {0: 'Hummer',
  1: 'GMC',
  2: 'Chevrolet',
  3: 'Plymouth',
  4: 'Smart',
  5: 'Volkswagen',
  6: 'Jeep',
  7: 'Toyota',
  8: 'Ford',
  9: 'Mercedes-Benz'}})
```

- No `values`:

`%timeit df.apply(lambda c: ''.join(c.astype(str)), axis=1)`

`1.29 ms ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

- With `values`:

`%timeit df.apply(lambda c: ''.join(c.values.astype(str)), axis=1)`

`646 µs ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: have you try `df.sum(1)
`

Comment: `values` is just the underlying numpy data.  There is additional overhead provided by a Series or Dataframe in Pandas, such as index checking. Hence why Pands is slower.

Comment: values transform the series into a nump array - "ndarrays are stored more efficiently than Python lists and allow mathematical operations to be vectorized, which results in significantly higher performance than with looping constructs in Python." - from: https://medium.com/@ericvanrees/pandas-series-objects-and-numpy-arrays-15dfe05919d7  - Also check 'Python for Data Analysis: Data Wrangling with Pandas, NumPy, and IPython by Wes McKinney"